# Best way to trim exactly one quote from each side of Java string

Tags: java, string

I want to be able to trim one quote from each side of a java string. Here are some examples.

`"foo"` -> `foo`

`"foo\""` -> `foo\"`

`"\"foo\""` -> `\"foo\"`

I'm currently using `StringUtils.trim` from common lang but when I end the string with a escaped quote, it trims that too because they are consecutive. I want to be able to trim *exactly* one quote.

Comment: `s.replaceAll("^(?!\\\\)\"|(?!\\\\)\"$")`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Is there not a simpler way? One that doesn't require an explanation. Something self-explanatory like a `trimOne` function or something.

Comment: [`if (s.startsWith("\"") && s.endsWith("\"")&&s.length()>1) { s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1); }`](http://ideone.com/K1CT4B)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringBetween` and it works.

Comment: If you know that there is definitely quotes around the string, then can you use the equivalent from String: `quotedString.substring(1, quotedString.length() -1)`

Comment: That's another good way which doesn't require a library. I might use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the substring() method and trim the first and last characters on condition although it's a bit long.

```
trimedString= s.substring((s.charAt(0)=='"')?1:0 , (s.charAt(s.length()-1)=='"')?s.length()-1:s.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this String method

public String[] split(String regex)

basically if you feed in the quotation mark then you will get an array of strings holding all of the chunks between your quotation marks.

```
String[] parts = originalString.split("\""); 
String quoteReduced = parts[0];
for (int i = 1; i < (parts.length() -1); i++){
    quoteReduced = quoteReduced.concat( parts[i] +"\"" );
}
quoteReduced = quoteReduced.concat( "\"" +parts[parts.length()-1]);
```

While it may not be the most straight forward it is the way that I would get around this.  The first piece and last piece could be included in the loop but would require an if statement.